# Automapper is it supported to map to self and flatter / perform maps on same object(s)

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a tree of objects. I would like to update the objects with some default values and flattening some propertied also.
However, I do not want to create a new object, just update the existing tree.
So I thought. Well, I can do it with a mass of logic and recursion. Or I could try it with the auto mapper. Basically map to self. And automapper might update the destination with the source. and perform the flatterning:

#### Source/destination types

```cs
public class Foo
    {
        public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Bar
    {
        public bool SomeBoolWithDefalting { get; set; }
    }
```

#### Mapping configuration

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Bar, Bar>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeBoolWithDefalting, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>true));
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var foo = new Foo
            {
                Bars = new List<Bar> { new Bar() }
            };
            mapper.Map<Foo, Foo>(foo, foo);
```

#### Version:

9.0.0

#### Expected behavior

I expected that Bars get updated with the default value. And foo and bars is the same object as before

#### Actual behavior

But all I got back is empty bars.

if I:

```cs
var newFoo = mapper.Map<Foo, Foo>(foo);
```

Then I get a new foo, with the bars updated.

I know auto mapper should be used to make new objects. But isn't. Is use case valid? performing flattering on a destination only?

#### Steps to reproduce

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Foo, Foo>();
                cfg.CreateMap<Bar, Bar>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeBoolWithDefalting, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => true));
            });
            var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

            var foo = new Foo
            {
                Bars = new List<Bar> { new Bar() } 
            };
            var newFoo = mapper.Map<Foo, Foo>(foo); //good bars, but new objects

            mapper.Map<Foo, Foo>(foo, foo); //same foo, but no bars
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Bars.First().SomeBoolWithDefalting);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** When mapping to an existing collection, AutoMapper clears the destination collection first.

---

#### Explanation

Let's add a `Name` property to your `Bar` class:

```cs
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool SomeBoolWithDefalting { get; set; }
}
```

Then run this mapping snippet below:

```cs
var newFoo = new Foo
{
    Bars = new List<Bar>
    {
        new Bar
        {
            Name = "Bar that will be mapped.",
        },
    },
};
var notEmptyFoo = new Foo()
{
    Bars = new List<Bar>
    {
        new Bar
        {
            Name = "Bar that will be removed.",
        }
    },
};

Console.WriteLine(notEmptyFoo.Bars.First().Name);

mapper.Map<Foo, Foo>(newFoo, notEmptyFoo);

Console.WriteLine(notEmptyFoo.Bars.First().Name);
```

Code above maps from `Foo` with one already existing `Bar` to another `Foo` also with already existing `Bar`. But AutoMapper will remove all `Bar`s from destination `Foo` (named in the snippet `notEmptyFoo`) just before the mapping process begin.

The console output will show:

```
Bar that will be removed.
Bar that will be mapped.
```

So, when you are mapping from and to the same `Foo`, not only the destination `Foo` bars are being cleared before the mapping, but also the source `Foo` as well as it's the same and one `Foo` object! So after the clearing there are no bars in the source `Foo` to map from, as it just got cleared.

If you would like to preserve elements of destination collection, take a look at [AutoMapper.Collection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) project. There you can set an EqualityComparison telling AutoMapper how to recognize the same elements when mapping between the collections.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks! I understand now... I will look at collections. thanks again :-)

Comment: You're supposed to mark it as an answer to the question, at least helpful, or both.